# Android HttpURLConnection - How to set HTTP/1.1 protocol?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

How can I set the HTTP protocol to HTTP/1.1 using HttpURLConnection?

Some setters I using:

```
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "300");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8;q=1,ISO-8859-1;q=0.9,*;q=0.5");
```

Comment: BY default it uses HTTP/1.1 and with HttpsUrlConnection class it is not possible